# Definition of Holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

If a function $f$  is not holomorphic at $z_0$, then for each $\epsilon>0$, $f$ is not differentiable on the open ball $B_{\epsilon}(z_0)$. Does this imply that $f$ is not differentiable at $z_0$? Is there a function $f$ that is complex differentiable at $z_0$ but not on any open ball around $z_0$?

Comment: Consider $f(z) = |z|^2.$

Comment: @zhw. I see, so since this function is differentiable only at $z=0$,  $f$ is differentiable at $z=0$ but not holomorphic at that point.